# all access to /mnt/ hangs ubuntu after a period

Tags: mount, cifs

Filesharing in Linux is probably not working!

My two cifs shares seems to work for a while, but when coming back the other day and access the mounts or just type in `ls /mnt/` hangs the terminal or whatever application I use to access the mounts.

The terminal also hangs when running the df command.

When the problem occurs I have no issue with one of the two shares:

```
ls /mnt/misc [OK]
ls /mnt/production [Hangs]
```

Here are the content of the `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.33.11/misc /mnt/misc/ cifs username=user,password=pw,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.33.11/production /mnt/misc/ cifs username=user,password=pw,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I can't see the difference of the two shares and I have no idea what to do next!

Thanks.

Comment: In the fstab you have pasted you are using `/mnt/misc/` for `//192.168.33.11/production`.

Answer (score 0):

First I got some errors that I removed from the post:

Starting smb/cifs file and active directory server [ Fail ]

> Just remove the file /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.conf that seems to duplicate the start of the server!

It didn't solve my issue though.

Comment: If this is not an answer please update your question by [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/699923/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the commands:

> sudo umount /mnt/production
>
> sudo mount -a

I really don't know why I have to "remount" the folder, but it's working.