# NFS mount to NAS folder causes /mnt directory to become unresponsive; NAS also becomes unresponsive

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs, nas

I've just spun up a new Asustor NAS on my network and have been deciding how I want to configure and connect to it.  I'm currently using NFS to mount shared folders I've created on the NAS.  While making transfers to the NAS from my desktop, two or three times now I've come back to see that the transfer has hung, I can't get a response from my NAS, and when I go to look into /mnt, with `ls`, for where I mounted the folders, my terminal hangs.  Trying to `umount` the folders also hangs.

I'm at a loss as to what the issue is, but I'm fairly new to using network drives and mounting folders so I'm hoping I'm simply missing something obvious.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699923/all-access-to-mnt-hangs-ubuntu-after-a-period) from years ago but there really seemed to be no answer given so I thought I'd post my specific issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Through more searching I also found this post, https://askubuntu.com/questions/701056/nfs-hangs-in-ubuntu-15-10  I'm starting to think I need to use a protocol other than NFS...